# No way to float right my input area in the nav bar - Why?

Tags: html, css, input, flexbox, css-float

I can't find a way to make my input field (a search box) and its relative icon (a magnifier lens) to `float` to the right of the navbar in my website (while leaving my logo on the left of the nav). Any suggestion?

HTML:

```
 <nav>
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="">
                    <h1>MyWebsiteName.com</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <form action="javascript:redirect()" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="form-control">
                <ul class=mylist list-group" id="result"></ul>  <!--this line is for JS-->
                <button type="submit">
                   <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 77 77" fill="none" 
                           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                   </svg> </button>
            </form>

        </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-container form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav input {
  font-size: 1.20em;
  border: solid 2px #E5E5E5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: none;
  color: #F4F4F4; 
  padding: 14px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  width: 260px;
}
form {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: May be.. we are not sure without seeing css done by you.

Comment: Sorry, added the CSS just now! @Manjuboyz

Comment: thanks for sharing the css and you have your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin-left: auto;` on the form instead of `float: right` - it's inside a flex container (`.nav-container`), where float will not be effective, but `margin-left: auto` will move it as far right as possible.

```css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-container form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav input {
  font-size: 1.20em;
  border: solid 2px #E5E5E5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: none;
  color: #F4F4F4;
  padding: 14px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  width: 260px;
}

form {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="">
        <h1>MyWebsiteName.com</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <form action="javascript:redirect()" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="form-control">
      <ul class=mylist list-group " id="result "></ul>     <!-- this line is for JS -->
                <button type="submit ">
                   <svg width="50 " height="50 " viewBox="0 0 77 77 " fill="none " 
                           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg ">
                   </svg> </button>
            </form>

        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it.

[flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

[grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

NOTE:

Due to space constraint in the snippet you have to view it in `full screen`.

> 1. I just used `position:absolute;` this will move your content towards `right`.
> 2. You can have a wrapper around those 2 input and use `flex` to keep those 2 items towards right.
> 3. Don't use `float` it has become old and it not very much flexible when you have your responsive design.

```css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-container form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav input {
  font-size: 1.20em;
  border: solid 2px #E5E5E5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: none;
  color: #F4F4F4;
  padding: 14px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  width: 260px;
}

.moveRight {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="">
        <h1>MyWebsiteName.com</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <form action="javascript:redirect()" autocomplete="off" class="moveRight">
      <input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="form-control">
      <ul class="mylist list-group" id="result"></ul>
      <!-- this line is for JS -->
      <button type="submit">
                   <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 77 77" fill="none" 
                           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                   </svg> </button>
    </form>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) I didn't know that float was considered old, what do you usually prefer for responsive design?

Comment: Glad it works! the `position:absolute;` will works for your case and for the responsiveness since it keeps the those 2 controls towards right always. When you consider to do any responsive design especially layout design try using either `flexbox` or `grid` these 2 are really good towards responsiveness design, start exploring those it will give you very good information.

Comment: I have added both `flexbox` and `grid` layout documentation which may help you further. happy coding.

Comment: Wonderful, I really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Missing this

```css
.nav-container {
justify-content: space-between;
}
```